# Generate Resource Logical Id name using a parameter in Sam template

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am using Sam template to deploy a lambda with a api gateway. 
Trying to generate a custom resource Logical Id based on a Timestamp.  for eg in example below:  ApiDeployment$TIMESTAMP$: which is not working. Any ideas how I may achieve a dynamically configurable resource Logical Id name, using Sam template?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Setup our API Gateway instances

Parameters:
  StageName:
    Type: String
    Default: 'example_stage'
    Description: 'The name of the stage to be created and managed within our API Gateway instance.'

Resources:

  Api:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
    Properties:
      Name: ExampleApi
      EndpointConfiguration: 
        Types: 
        - REGIONAL

      # The body should contain the actual swagger
      Body: $SWAGGER_DEFINITION$

  # Timestamp is added so that each deployment is unique. Without a new timestamp, the deployment will not actually occur
  ApiDeployment$TIMESTAMP$:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    DependsOn: [ Api ]
    # we want to retain our deployment history
    DeletionPolicy: Retain    
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: Api

  ApiStage:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
    DependsOn: [ApiDeployment$TIMESTAMP$]
    Properties:
      RestApiId:
        Ref: Api
      DeploymentId:
        Ref: ApiDeployment$TIMESTAMP$
      StageName: {Ref: StageName}
      MethodSettings:
        - ResourcePath: "/*"
          HttpMethod: "*"
          LoggingLevel: INFO
          MetricsEnabled: true
          DataTraceEnabled: true

Outputs:
  Endpoint:
    Description: Endpoint url
    Value:
      Fn::Sub: 'https://${Api}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com'
```

Comment: did you ever get any further on this issue?  I have the same need.